# Android data class structure for unlabelled API response

Tags: android, api, kotlin

An API is returning responses without any outlying data fields, but instead only as an array object like this:

`[{"name":"John Smith", "age":"44", "address":"1 Main Street, Anywhere, USA"}, {"name":"Jane Taylor", "age":"22", "address":"10 Suburbia Lane, Sometown, USA"},{"name":"Simon Jones", "age":"36", "address":"33 City Boulevard, Midvalley, USA"}]`

My response data classes usually include labels, like this:

```
data class MyResponseClass (
  val status: String? = null,
  val description: String? = null
)
```

How should I structure a response class that does not include labels?

TIA.

---

**UPDATE:**

Following Ivo's answer *(thank you, btw)*, how could such a class inherit a base class?

```
open class MyBaseReponseClass() : Serializable {
   val status: String? = null
   val description: String? = null
}

data class MyResponseClass (
  val name: String? = null,
  val age: String? = null,
  val address: String? = null
) : MyBaseReponseClass()
```

The **name, age, and address** are in an array, but not **status and description**.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean with not using labels. it clearly has `name`, `age` and `address` so it will be

```
data class MyResponseClass (
  val name: String? = null,
  val age: String? = null
  val address: String? = null
)
```

And where you indicate the type of the response you say it's a `List<MyResponseClass>`